# How to split a string between two specified chars in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like to split a `String` in between for instance `(` and `)` so that i get a list of all substrings.

example:

```
"foo (bar) foo (foo2) bar (foo3)"
```

results in `["bar","foo2","foo3"]`

i tried using `findIndices` and then mapping `splitAt` on to the string but this was not working...

Comment: What do you want to do for inputs with mismatched or nested parentheses, like e.g. `"foo (foo1 (foo2) foo3) (bar( baz) quux"`?

Comment: it should return: 

[(foo1 (foo2)foo3), (bar( baz)]

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to account for nested parentheses when they are matched, but not when you have mismatched parentheses?

Comment: Make use of a library like `parsec`, or otherwise use explicit recursion where you keep track of the number of open parenthesis this far.

Comment: @bradrn exactly.

Comment: @asdasdasdasdas In that case, I second @WillemVanOnsem’s suggestion of using a parsing library or explicit recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Data.Void
import Control.Monad
```

This [**megaparsec**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) pattern will match the contents of balanced parentheses, but will omit the outer parentheses.

```
let balancedParens :: Parsec Void String String
    balancedParens = do
        char '('
        join <$> manyTill
            ((fst <$> match balancedParens) <|> (pure <$> anySingle))
            (char ')')
```

Now with [`splitCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:splitCap) from [**replace-megaparsec**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec):

```
splitCap balancedParens "foo (bar) foo (foo2) bar (foo3)"
```

```
[Left "foo ",Right "bar",Left " foo ",Right "foo2",Left " bar ",Right "foo3"]
```

You said you wanted different behavior here for the unbalanced parenthesis case, but maybe you can adjust it to give the behavior that you want.

```
splitCap balancedParens "foo (foo1 (foo2) foo3) (bar( baz) quux"
```

```
[Left "foo ",Right "foo1 (foo2) foo3",Left " (bar",Right " baz",Left " quux"]
```